# Non-determinism vs nondeterminism

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Reading articles I came across the word non-determinism written in different ways (non-determinism and nondeterminism).
I was wondering if there is a difference, or if one is incorrect? May be one is from the UK and the other from the UK?

More generally what is the "rule" for the "non-" composed words?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Non-" words are almost always composed without a hyphen. The exception is when the word to which this prefix is added is a proper noun, as with "non-Hispanic."

There is a list of "non-" words in the Merriam-Webster entry:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non-

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non-) has: << The prefix non- may be joined to a word by means of a hyphen, which is standard in British usage. In many cases, especially in American usage, non- is joined without a hyphen. >> Thus AHDEL gives nonagression whereas [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/non-aggression) gives non-aggression. The UK Government speaks of non-agricultural land. BT has  'Non-Automated Payment Methods'. Neither the solid nor the hyphenated forms can usually be called incorrect; the best option is to check in a dictionary (or several).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good addition with the British usage!

Comment: All those hyphens being thrown out of the plane half way to New York....